# Rename a file before Copy Task in ant build

Tags: build, ant

I am new to ant build files. 
Currently I get a list of files for build as:

```
a.cls
b.cls
c.cls
```

but in my local I have to run build on files, in the same directory:

```
a-meta.cls
b-meta.cls
c-meta.cls
```

Here `meta` keyword stays consistent. And I am using the following build.xml file. I am not sure how can I rename filename before actually copying them. I tried `replace`, `mapper` and other `antlib` tasks. But not helpful.

```
<project name="test" default="compile">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <loadfile property="file" srcfile="filesToMove.txt"/> <!-- these are the list of files, i mentioned earlier -->
    <target name="compile">
        <echo>${file}</echo> <!-- here i have to rename file name to include -meta -->
        <copy file="./classes/${file}" tofile="./src/classes/${file}" overwrite="true"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

How to rename the files before moving them.

Comment: It looks like you're copying the files rather than moving them.  Would copying from the original-named sources to the new-named (with -meta) destination meet your requirements?

Comment: got the solution to this...would update as answer

Answer (score 0):

The solution to it was replacing the `.cls` to find only the name and then append the `-meta.html`. As follows (some portion is changed compared to previous version in the question)

```
<project name="test" default="compile">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <loadfile property="file" srcfile="filesToMove.txt"/> <!-- these are the list of files, i mentioned earlier -->
    <target name="compile">
        <echo>${file}</echo> <!-- here i have to rename file name to include -meta -->
        <copy file="./classes/${file}" tofile="./src/classes/${file}" overwrite="true"/>
        <for param="file">
            <path>
                <fileset dir="./" includes="*.cls"/>
            </path>
            <sequential>
                <basename file="@{file}" property="@{file}" suffix=".md"/>
                <echo message=" ${@{file}}"/>
                <copy file="${@{file}}-meta.cls" toDir="test"/>
            </sequential>
        </for> 
    </target>
</project>
```